# VBA Advanced Filter with And ,Or Criteria range

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I am trying to set up an advanced filter with multiple criteria range ( And, Or operators )
the problem is when I run the code the results that appear are related to the last row in the criteria range while the previous rows are missing

According to the code
Num refers to the last row in the criteria table (F to I)

```
If Sheet11.Range("P2,Q2,R2").Value <> Empty Then
Set AFCRange = Sheet1.Range("F3:I" & Num) 'Advanced Filter Criteria Range
Sheet13.Range("I1:A" & lastRow).CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=AFCRange, _
CopyToRange:=Sheet3.Range("K2:C2"), Unique:=False
End If

End With
```

Comment: FYI `If Sheet11.Range("P2,Q2,R2").Value <> Empty Then` only looks at P2

Comment: Sorry , Can you explain more ?

Comment: If you call `Value` on a non-contiguous range (and "P2,Q2,R2" is not the same as "P2:R2" in that respect) then you only get the value of the first `Area` in that range.  So, your code only checks the value of P2.   Use something like `Application.CountA(Range("P2:R2"))` instead.

Comment: I tried that, But I still have the same problem, The results that appear related to the criteria in the last row while other criteria in previous rows in the criteria table  are missing

Comment: It will be difficult to debug that without knowing what your data table and filter range look like.

Comment: Do you have any problem with chatting?

Comment: Sorry I'm busy right now and actually don't too much like the "chat" approach. If you can add screenshots (suitable redacted if required) of your data and filter ranges then that would help.